# Washed out materials but good textures, why?

Tags: texturing, materials

Sorry for the newbie question, but I can't seem to find the correct answer (and what I found I can't really understand, since I just started using the software 1 day ago. I wanted to create some fly-over video in my indoor room models, what I created with photogrammetry.

This is how my textures look: 
[image]

And this is how my material view looks:
[image]

What can be the reason of this? I saw some answers about nodes, but when I opened mine, there was nothing. Also, I have limited time, my thesis defense is after tomorrow, and the idea of creating a video about my models just popped up yesterday, therefore I can't really get deep into it in the next day.

Any help is well appreciated!

Comment: Found the problem: somehow in the "Influence" inside the "Material" window, the Specular --> Color were turned off. Turned it on, and voilá, it's perfect.